# Change bind event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, bind

I am using an jQuery plugin to overlay image effects on mouseover. since i don't want to have them effects only shown by mouseover but directly when the site has loaded, I am trying to change that code:

```
//binding events for mouseover
$(this).parent().bind('click',function(){
    if(settings.hoverEffect=='normal')
    {
        ......
```

The tricky part is the:

```
$(this).parent().bind('click',function(){
```

I need a way to get rid of the 'click' function, I tried 'ready' but it doesn't work. can anyone help me out with that? I basically just need the function to be run when the page has loaded, or even better the image the effect will be applied on (this).parent.

Comment: I suggest you post more code, and try to create a testcase on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).parent().bind('click',function(){
        if(settings.hoverEffect=='normal') {
            ......
        }
     });
     $(this).parent().trigger('click');
});
```

`trigger` immitates a click on the specified element and will trigger the function. Done this way you don't have to create double up of the function